# How can I return the difference between two lists?

Tags: java, list, object, filtering

I have two array lists e.g.

```
List<Date> a;
contains : 10/10/2014, 10/11/2016

List<Date> b;
contains : 10/10/2016
```

How can i do a check between list `a` and `b` so the value that is missing in `b` is returned?e.g. `10/10/2014`

Comment: guava has some tools for differences but it's for `Set`, I think a `removeAll` might suits you here

Comment: Copy list `a`. Remove all elements that appear in `b` from the copy.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: If you want the disjunction between the two, CollectionUtil has a disjunction method that returns the difference.

Comment: This might be referring to `CollectionUtils.subtract` from Apache Commons Collections; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714028/227779) for more details.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can convert them to `Set` collections, and perform a set difference operation on them.

Like this:

```
Set<Date> ad = new HashSet<Date>(a);
Set<Date> bd = new HashSet<Date>(b);
ad.removeAll(bd);
```

Comment: `removeAll` returns a `boolean` not a `Set`

Comment: That's correct, but when you look at the documentation you will see that this boolean informs wether or not "this set changed as a result of the call". After this change you can adres the Set and you'll notice it has the results you expected.

Comment: Creating `bd` `HashSet` is unnecessary. You can just call `ad.removeAll(b)`.

Comment: what if bd has more elements than ad? what happens in that case?

Answer (score 50):

If you only want find missing values in b, you can do:

```
List toReturn = new ArrayList(a);
toReturn.removeAll(b);

return toReturn;
```

If you want to find out values which are present in either list you can execute upper code twice. With changed lists.

Comment: what if its unmodifiable list?

Comment: Since you create a new list, this is working also for an unmodifiable list.

Answer (score 37):

I was looking similar but I wanted the difference in either list (uncommon elements between the 2 lists).

Let say I have:

```
List<String> oldKeys = Arrays.asList("key0","key1","key2","key5");
List<String> newKeys = Arrays.asList("key0","key2","key5", "key6");
```

And I wanted to know which key has been added and which key is removed i.e I wanted to get `(key1, key6)`

Using `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(CollectionUtils.disjunction(newKeys, oldKeys));
```

**Result**

```
["key1", "key6"]
```

Comment: Could you point me to the maven repository for the same. I tried this `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.4` But it does not seem to be the right one.

Comment: @paradocslover it was https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Any idea what is the function renamed to in the newer versions of the package?

Answer (score 26):

You can use `filter` in the Java 8 `Stream` library

```
List<String> aList = List.of("l","e","t","'","s");
List<String> bList = List.of("g","o","e","s","t");

List<String> difference = aList.stream()
    .filter(aObject -> {
        return ! bList.contains(aObject);
      })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

//more reduced: no curly braces, no return
List<String> difference2 = aList.stream()
    .filter(aObject -> ! bList.contains(aObject))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Result of `System.out.println(difference);`:

> [e, t, s]

Comment: Thanks stranger!

Comment: welcome @Teekam Suthar =)

Answer (score 9):

You can use CollectionUtils from [Apache Commons Collections 4.0](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html):

```
new ArrayList<>(CollectionUtils.subtract(a, b))
```

Comment: Note: this approach does not support generics in any way, so what you get is a raw, un-checked `Collection` instance.

Comment: The method signature is: `public static <O> Collection<O> subtract(Iterable<? extends O> a, Iterable<? extends O> b)`, and according to documentation: "O - the generic type that is able to represent the types contained in both input collections."

Comment: You are indeed correct; mea culpa. I was looking at the 3.2 version of the class where the method has a simple `public static Collection subtract(final Collection a, final Collection b)` signature. Great to see that they have improved on this in the 4.0 iteration.

Answer (score 6):

First convert list to sets.

```
// create an empty set 
Set<T> set = new HashSet<>(); 

// Add each element of list into the set 
for (T t : list) 
    set.add(t);
```

You can use `Sets.difference(Set1, Set2)`, which returns extra items present in Set1.
You can use `Sets.difference(Set2, Set1)`, which returns extra items present in Set2.

Comment: Wow, nice solution. I have never known about this class

Answer (score 5):

With Stream API you can do something like this:

```java
List<String> aWithoutB = a.stream()
    .filter(element -> !b.contains(element))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> bWithoutA = b.stream()
    .filter(element -> !a.contains(element))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generic solution for this problem.

```
public <T> List<T> difference(List<T> first, List<T> second) {
    List<T> toReturn = new ArrayList<>(first);
    toReturn.removeAll(second);
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: That will come in handy in most situations. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You may call `Underscore.difference(lists)` method in [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/tIG)

```
import com.github.underscore.Underscore;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
        List<Integer> list3 = Underscore.difference(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(list3);
        // [3]
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the list2 also contains some extra value. 
list2 = {1,2,4,5}.

Expected list3  = {3,4,5}

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
l1.add("apple");
l1.add("orange");
l1.add("banana");
l1.add("strawberry");

List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
l2.add("apple");
l2.add("orange");

System.out.println(l1);
System.out.println(l2);

for (String A: l2) {
  if (l1.contains(A))
    l1.remove(A);
}

System.out.println("output");
System.out.println(l1);
```

Output:

```
[apple, orange, banana, strawberry]
[apple, orange]
output
[banana, strawberry]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a different problem and came across this, so I will add my solution to a related problem: comparing two Maps.

```
    // make a copy of the data
    Map<String,String> a = new HashMap<String,String>(actual);
    Map<String,String> e = new HashMap<String,String>(expected);
    // check *every* expected value
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> val : e.entrySet()){
        // check for presence
        if(!a.containsKey(val.getKey())){
            System.out.println(String.format("Did not find expected value: %s", val.getKey()));
        }
        // check for equality
        else{
            if(0 != a.get(val.getKey()).compareTo(val.getValue())){
                System.out.println(String.format("Value does not match expected: %s", val.getValue()));
            }
            // we have found the item, so remove it 
            // from future consideration. While it 
            // doesn't affect Java Maps, other types of sets
            // may contain duplicates, this will flag those
            // duplicates. 
            a.remove(val.getKey());
        }
    }
    // check to see that we did not receive extra values
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> val : a.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(String.format("Found unexpected value: %s", val.getKey()));
    }
```

It works on the same principle as the other solutions but also compares not only that values are present, but that they contain the same value. Mostly I've used this in accounting software when comparing data from two sources (Employee and Manager entered values match; Customer and Corporate transactions match; ... etc)

Comment: I wasn't aware of a question regarding maps. If you have found a question that was asking about maps, do feel free to link to this answer.

Comment: Answers should address the question asked. If you think you have a useful code snippet / explanation for something where no question exists, ask the question yourself and self-answer it using the built-in site function. Don't post your answer under an unrelated question.

Comment: The difference between my answer and the question is not the use of `Map` vs `List`. The difference lies with the question asking only for missing values, I addressed "missing, added, and equality" of values. I would be concerned if an answer seeker could not see the ways in which `Map`, `Set`, and `List` are related concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Set is a map underneath i was able to get the diff between two list over a million entries each wrapping it in a HashSet this is a simple code to do it.

```
private List<String>notPresentMethod(final List<String>left,final List<String>right){
    final Set<String>setIsFaster = new HashSet<>(right);
    return left.stream()
            .filter(((Predicate<String>)setIsFaster::contains).negate())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Using only list took over a hour and did not complete. And using this sample took Just seconds.