# Java - Getting Difference Between Two Lists

Tags: java

I am trying to find the difference between two lists in Java. I am using this example ([returning difference between two lists in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002882/returning-difference-between-two-lists-in-java/27002940)) that suggests to use `removeAll()` to find the difference but that is not working. Instead, I seem to be getting a combined list of `coaches` and `teachers`.

Code:

```
List<String> coaches = new ArrayList<>();
coaches.add("Josh");
coaches.add("Jake");
coaches.add("Tyler");

List<String> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
coaches.add("Josh");
coaches.add("Jake");

coaches.removeAll(teachers);

for (String name : coaches) {
    System.out.println("Name is: " + name);
}
```

Output:

```
Name is: Josh
Name is: Jake
Name is: Tyler
Name is: Josh
Name is: Jake
```

How would I check that `teachers` is missing the value `Tyler` so `Tyler` would be returned?

Comment: *"... but that is not working"* - How is it not working?  Show us an MCVE.

Comment: Doing this `coaches.removeAll(teachers);` will leave you with "Tyler" in your example, letting you know that `teachers` did not contain "Tyler"...

Comment: I have updated my question to show what I am seeing

Comment: You did `coaches.add` twice instead of `teachers.add`...

Comment: I really simplified my example above. Would removeAll() also work against a List of Classes? (I didn't think a list of Strings and Classes will cause a difference)

Comment: @Jon it doesn't matter if you're using `String` or some other class: if you're calling `coaches.removeAll(teachers)` when the `teachers` is empty, nothing is going to happen to `coaches`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, to see who is just a coach and not also a teacher without losing your list of coaches:

```
List<String> coaches = new ArrayList<>();
coaches.add("Josh");
coaches.add("Jake");
coaches.add("Tyler");

List<String> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
teachers.add("Josh");
teachers.add("Jake");

List<String> CoachesNotAlsoTeachers = new ArrayList<>();
CoachesNotAlsoTeachers.add(coaches);
CoachesNotAlsoTeachers.removeAll(teachers);

for (String name : CoachesNotAlsoTeachers ) {
    System.out.println("Name is: " + name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake in my example. I actually simplified my example too much I think. In my working issue I am using a List of Objects instead of a List of Strings. Should `removeAll()` still behave the same?

Comment: Yes, as long as they are the same kind of objects.