# More exhaustive way of comparing objects

Tags: java, object

I have to make implement the data structure for a search engine. So there are different type of objects in my DS. I have a generic linked list and I want to only add those elements to the list which are not a part of the list now. Is there a method for comparing two object types in a more exhaustive way because .equals() is returning true every time?

```
public Boolean IsMember(T o) {
    NodeX<T> temp = head;

    while(temp!= null) {
        if (temp.data.equals(o))
            {//System.out.println("exec");
            return true;}
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is the isMember method of the LinkedList. This works only for string types. What can I change in this to make it work for all object types?

If I define an isEqual method for different objects that I am using, how can I use those methods here?

Comment: If i understand it right, you can override equals and compare what you want.

Comment: I have an isMember method in my linked list. I am using equals there. How can I override that?

Comment: Maybe i understand it wrong... but you can override the equals method from the objects itself and compare them there. Otherwise please add a little code example for your problem, think that helps :)

Comment: I edited the question. Could you please suggest anything now?

Comment: What type is ´temp.data´

Comment: temp is just a generic node of the LinkedList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you define an isEqual method for different objects, that is the method that is used whenever isEqual is called, like in isMember.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement your version of .equals(). To compare lists here are some questions would be helpful for you

[returning difference between two lists in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002882/returning-difference-between-two-lists-in-java)

[Simple way to find if two different lists contain exactly the same elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075656/simple-way-to-find-if-two-different-lists-contain-exactly-the-same-elements)

[Java Compare Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)