# Best way to find uncommon elements inside list

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am having lists of `String` type say list `aLista` and `bListb` first list might have at max `10 elements` however `bListb` might have thousand or even more elements. Now i have to find all elements from `aList` which are not in `bListb` . Here is my approach

```
List<String> aLista = Arrays.asList("Anil","Abhishek","Ritu");
List<String> bListb = Arrays.asList("g","o","e","Abhishek","Ritu");

List<String> result3 = aLista.stream().filter(al -> 
!bListb.contains(al)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result3);
// output Anil
```

But i am not sure about performance as `bListb` might have much elements later on . So i just came to know about best optimum way of doing this. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a set. Contains for a HashSet is O(1) compared to O(n) for a list, therefore you should never use a list if you often need to run contains.

```
Set<String> bSet = new HashSet<>(bListb);
aLista.stream().filter(a -> !bSet.contains(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the duplicates, then try this:

```
Set<String> uncommon = new HashSet<>(aLista);
uncommon.removeAll(bListb);
```

Comment: how about `uncommon.removeAll(new HashSet<>(bListb))` ? `bListb` could be huge as OP pointed (might optimise a bit further) ?

Comment: Yes, it would in most cases. I just thought there is no point to duplicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27002913/10584605) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `aLista` is very limited in size and `bListb` is potentially huge, you should convert `aLista` to a `Set`, not `bListb`.

```
Set<String> missing = new HashSet<>(aLista);
for (String s : bListb) {
    if (missing.isEmpty())
        break;
    missing.remove(s);
}
```

The code will even short-circuit the iteration of `bListb` if all values have been found, whereas converting `bListb` to a `Set` would not allow such short-circuit logic.