# How to find the difference between two ArrayList<Integer> in Java without using Java 8 Stream?

Tags: java, android, arrays

This might look like a duplicate but it's not, read through the end please.
**Some context :** I'm building an android app that connect to an api. There's a checkbox of items "finishes" applied to a furniture object, when I'm updating the the finishes I must send back to the backend the finishes(checkbox)I want to delete. `finishes_to_be_removed: []` and pass there ids in the array, while adding finishes is `finishes: []`. The problem is, I want to find a way to diff the the two list generated from the checkboxes, the old one and the updated one. So I can populate the `finishes_to_be_removed: []`.

I cannot use Java 8 Stream because my API level min is 15.

When I try list.contains(list2), it tells "List may not contains object of Type List.

**I want to return items that are in the first list but that are not on the second list only**, not a 1:1 comparison.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27002940/2958086 An answer in that dupe

Comment: @Compass the first answer is still a good approach, only one thing to mention : if the original `List` contains duplicates, converting it to a `Set` will eliminates them.

Answer (score 1):

`List.contains()` takes an element of the same type as the `List`, i.e. a `List<String>` lets you call `list.contains("some string")`, but you cannot pass another `List<String>` into `.contains()`.

An example function that could work looks like:

```
public boolean <T> listContains(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    for (T t : list1) {  // iterate through all elements of list1

        if (list2.contains(list1)) return true;  // check to see if list2 contains each element

    }

    return false;  // return false if no matches found
}
```

EDIT

After seeing your edit, if you want to get only the elements that are in the first list, but not in the second list, you can use:

```
list1.removeIf(item -> list2.contains(item));
```

This removes all items from `list1` that are contained in `list2`